# Custom delegation to pass data between tab bar view in iOS not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, delegation

I am facing a problem related to delegation.I have 2 tabView. In first tabview i have 2 textfield and a button(to trigger the delegate method) and in the second tabview i have 2 label to display the content of textfield in the first tabview.Whats wrong with my code???

For first tabviewA the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewControllerA;
@protocol ViewControllerADelegate <NSObject>
-(void)sayHello:(ViewControllerA*)viewController;
@end
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldFirst;
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldSecond;
@property (nonatomic,strong)id<ViewControllerADelegate>delegate;
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender;
@end
```

and the .m file

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerA ()
@end
@implementation ViewControllerA
@synthesize textFieldFirst=_textFieldFirst;
@synthesize textFieldSecond=_textFieldSecond;
@synthesize delegate=_delegate;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _textFieldFirst.delegate=self;
    _textFieldSecond.delegate=self;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate sayHello:self];
}

@end
```

And for the second tabbarViewB the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController<ViewControllerADelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UILabel *labelFirst;
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UILabel *labelSecond;

@end
```

and the .m file

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

@synthesize labelFirst=_labelFirst;
@synthesize labelSecond=_labelSecond;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewControllerA *viewControllerA=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    viewControllerA.delegate=self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(void)sayHello:(ViewControllerA *)viewController
{
    _labelFirst.text=viewController.textFieldFirst.text;
    _labelSecond.text=viewController.textFieldSecond.text;
}

@end
```

N.B: I have tried tabView B to tabview A with the same process and that worked fine. The reverse (i.e from A to B)is not working at all.Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing and did you check that "sayHello" is called on ViewControllerB and are the text values not nil?

Comment: At what point is it 'not working'? Have you put breakpoints in the code and check that the next: IBACtion is being called and if so whether the delegate is set correctly etc?

Comment: If ViewControllerA is the first thing to be displayed, has ViewControllerB had any chance to set itself as a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewControllerB sets itself as the delegate in its `viewDidLoad` method. This method is called as soon as the View Controller has loaded the view it manages (into its `view` property). That view is loaded only when someone tries to access the view controller's `view` property for the first time. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2). There's a good chance that ViewControllerB's view has not been loaded yet, so the `viewDidLoad` method has not been called yet.

If you override the `awakeFromNib` method like so:

```
(void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    ViewControllerA *viewControllerA=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers
                                      objectAtIndex:0];
    viewControllerA.delegate = self;
}
```

it should work, since that method will be called when the view controller is initialized.